# Advice for updating my deliveries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editing

I am new to MVC and have a slight problem. So basically I have deliveries and within deliveries I have three attributes that can be updated: Driver, Vehicle and Status. The problem I have is that when the user goes to the edit delivery screen they are presented with three drop down lists, driver, vehicle (Driver and vehicle are populated based on availability) and status, now here is where the problem.

If the user only wants to update just the status they will change the status and click save. But then it updates to what ever is in the driver and vehicle drop down even though the user didn't change it.

For example:

If the current driver is Sipho, and Vehicle xxx 123. If a user wants to change the status to Delivered he will go the the edit delivery screen and change the drop down to "Delivered" but Driver Gus and Vehicle yyy 123 will be in the dropdowns (Because they are currently available) and will change it to this driver and vehicle eve though the user didn't want to change them.

How can I avoid this?

[image: Here is a screen shot of the edit screen:]

This is my view code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new { delivery_date = Model.delivery_date }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <section class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">Delivery Information</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DeliveryID)

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "Driver", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", null,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id="employee" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VehicleID, "Truck", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("VehicleID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleID)
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.delivery_status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Status field is required." id="dropdown" name="delivery_status">

                            <option>Dispatched</option>
                            <option>Completed</option>
                            <option>Problem Encountered</option>
                        </select>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.delivery_status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
            <section class="panel">

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;" />
                    <a href="~/Delivery/Index" data-toggle="modal" class="btn  btn-info">
                        Back
                    </a>

                </div>
            </section>
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.delivery_date, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.delivery_date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.delivery_date)
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my Delivery Controller Edit:

```
  // GET: /Delivery1/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            DELIVERY delivery = db.Delivery.Find(id);
            if (delivery == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employee.Where(o => o.employee_role == "Driver" && o.employee_status=="Available"), "EmployeeID", "employee_name");
            ViewBag.VehicleID = new SelectList(db.Vehicle.Where(o=> o.vehicle_status=="Available"), "VehicleID", "VehicleID");
            return View(delivery);
        }

        // POST: /Delivery1/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="DeliveryID,EmployeeID,VehicleID,delivery_date,delivery_status")] DELIVERY delivery)
        {
            var order = from ord in db.Order where ord.DeliveryID == delivery.DeliveryID select ord;
            var vehicle = from ord in db.Vehicle where ord.VehicleID == delivery.VehicleID select ord;
            var employee = from ord in db.Employee where ord.EmployeeID == delivery.EmployeeID select ord;
            if(delivery.EmployeeID == null)
            {
                int Delivery = Convert.ToInt32 (from ord in db.Delivery where ord.DeliveryID == delivery.DeliveryID select ord.EmployeeID);
                delivery.EmployeeID = Delivery;
            }
            foreach (ORDER ord in order)
            {
                if (delivery.delivery_status.Equals("Completed"))
                {
                    ord.order_status = "Delivered";

                }
                else if (delivery.delivery_status.Equals("Dispatched"))
                {
                    ord.order_status = "Enroute";
                }
                else if (delivery.delivery_status.Equals("Problem Encountered"))
                {
                    ord.order_status = "Delayed";
                }
                // Insert any additional changes to column values.
            }
            foreach (VEHICLE ord in vehicle)
            {
                if (delivery.delivery_status.Equals("Completed"))
                {
                    ord.vehicle_status = "Available";
                }
                // Insert any additional changes to column values.
            }
            foreach (EMPLOYEE ord in employee)
            {
                if (delivery.delivery_status.Equals("Completed"))
                {
                    ord.employee_status = "Available";
                }
                // Insert any additional changes to column values.
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(delivery).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employee, "EmployeeID", "employee_role", delivery.EmployeeID);
            ViewBag.VehicleID = new SelectList(db.Vehicle, "VehicleID", "vehicle_status", delivery.VehicleID);
            return View(delivery);
        }
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you asking. If the value of `DriverID` in the model is `Sipho`, then `Sipho` will be selected in the dropdown when you first render the view (not `Gus`). If its not displaying `Sipho`, then there is something else wrong in your code

Comment: Hi my Driver combo box is populated based on the driver availability. So if Sipho was selected for the delivery when you create then he will be changed to Unavailable and therefore will not be in the Combo box when you want to update. You cannot assign a new driver to the delivery if they are unvailable and therefore wont be in the combo box

Comment: But why not just include `Sipho` in the options so that when you render the page, `Sipho` will be selected, and then you wont have any issues (you can check in the controller if the value has changed from the original)

Comment: But other drivers that are unavailable will show on the list. And wont that only work because Sipho is at the top of the list. If Gus was selected first then when you load the page, Gus will be there but he will be below Sipho and therefore Sipho will be selected by default

Comment: No they wont. You just need the correct query - `db.Employee.Where((o => o.employee_role == "Driver" && o.employee_status=="Available") || DriverID == delivery.DriverID)`

Comment: Hi no if I selected Gus when I created the delivery and then I go edit the delivery, Sipho will still be in the DropdownList because he is at the top. Maybe I should sort by something when I fill the DropDownList

Comment: That because of other errors in your code (sorry to be harsh but its awful). If you do this correctly then if `Gus` is the original driver, the `Gus` will be displayed in the dropdownlist (wont matter if he is the last option)

Comment: So what can you suggest I do to correct this?

Comment: You really need to be using a view model, and I will post an answer a bit later, but the first thing you need to do is change the `ViewBag` property name to (say) `DriverList` (it cannot be the same name as the model property name) and then use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmployeeID, (SelectList)Model.DriverList)` - and ditto for all the other select lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are not strongly binding to you model properties, and as a result, the first option in your dropdownlist will be the selected one (because something has to be). And from your comments it also appears that you do not include the current Driver in the list of options, so you need to adjust you query to include it. You should first start by creating a view model to represent only what you need to display/edit

```
public class DeliveryVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public int Driver{ get; set; }
  public SelectList DriverList { get; set; }
  public int Truck { get; set; }
  public SelectList TruckList { get; set; }
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public SelectList StatusList { get; set; } 
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
  ....
  Delivery delivery = db.Delivery.Find(id);
  ....
  DeliveryVM model = new DeliveryVM()
  {
    ID = delivery.DeliveryID,
    Driver = delivery.EmployeeID,
    // ditto for vehicle and status
  };
  ConfigureEditModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(DeliveryVM model) // no [Bind] attribute
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) // do this first
  {
    ConfigureEditModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  Delivery delivery = db.Delivery.Find(model.ID);
  // map the view model properties to the data model
  ...
  // save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureEditModel(DeliveryVM model)
{
  var statusList = new List<string>{ "Dispatched", "Completed", "Problem Encountered" };
  model.StatusList = new SelectList(statusList);
  // modify query to ensure the current driver is included
  var driverList =  db.Employee.Where(e => (e.employee_role == "Driver" && e.employee_status=="Available") || e.DriverID == delivery.DriverID);
  model.DriverList = new SelectList(driverList, "EmployeeID", "employee_name");
  // ditto for vehicles
}
```

And in the view

```
@model DeliveryVM
....
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID) // not required if you have the default route with ../{id}
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Driver)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Driver, Model.DriverList) // the option matching the current Driver will be selected
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Driver)
  // ditto for Truck and Status
  <input type="submit" ../>
}
```

Comment: Just checking. Is it correct for status to be an int?

Comment: Oops - should be `string`. But I would actually consider using an `enum` for this anyway

Comment: What do you mean when you say  // map the view model properties to the data model?

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.DELIVERY_04217E89F5F729BACD7581A4CF69C639AA45DC64A17BE12C8D7C7DCDDB9E5F1E', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Mike.View_Models.DeliveryVM'. I am getting this error

Comment: In the GET method, you get the data model (i.e. `db.Delivery.Find(id)`) and initialize a view model and set its properties based on the values of the data model - i.e. _you map the data model to view model_. In the POST method you do the opposite. You get the data model from the data base again, and then update its properties based on the values in the view model i.e _you map the view model to data model_.

Comment: The error means you are not passing the view model to the view (my code initializes a new view model - `DeliveryVM model = new DeliveryVM()....` and returns it to the view using `return View(model);` so you have obviously not used my code correctly.

Comment: I've created this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l49bI4) so you can better understand. Note that there a 4 employees and 2 are marked as not avaliable (including Gus who is the current driver), but the query includes Gus. And Gus is selected even though he is not the first one in the list. Note also I has a typo in the query which is now corrected.

Comment: Please could you give the first line of code in order to map, because I am getting an error

Comment: Do you mean to map from the view model to the data model in the POST method?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your doing in the POST method, but you first get the data model - `Delivery delivery = db.Delivery.Find(model.ID);` and then set its properties based on the view model properties, for example `delivery.EmpoyeeID = model.Driver; delivery.VehicleID =  model.Truck;` etc and then save as your currently doing.

Comment: I mapped all the data but its giving me an error, it doesnt want to save (db.saveChanges())